# How to compute nested group proportions using python pandas without losing original row count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

Given the following data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'where': ['a','a','a','a','a','a'] +  ['b','b','b','b','b','b'],
    'what': ['x','y','z','x','y','z'] +  ['x','y','z','x','y','z'],
    'val' : [1,3,2,5,4,3] + [5,6,3,4,5,3]
})
```

Which looks as:

```
   where what  val
0      a    x    1
1      a    y    3
2      a    z    2
3      a    x    5
4      a    y    4
5      a    z    3
6      b    x    5
7      b    y    6
8      b    z    3
9      b    x    4
10     b    y    5
11     b    z    3
```

I would like to compute the proportion of `what` in `where`, and create a new
column that represented this.

The column will have duplicates, If I consider `what = x` in the above, and
add that column in then the data would be as follows

```
   where what  val   what_where_prop
0      a    x    1         6/18
1      a    y    3
2      a    z    2
3      a    x    5         6/18
4      a    y    4
5      a    z    3
6      b    x    5         9/26
7      b    y    6
8      b    z    3
9      b    x    4         9/26
10     b    y    5
11     b    z    3
```

Here `6/18` is computed by finding the total `x` (`6 = 1 + 5`) in `a` over the total of `val` in `a`. The same process is taken for `9/26`

The full solution will be filled similarly for `y` and `z` in the final column.

Comment: can you provide a sample dataframe, where values in what can be found in where. the current dataframe has not values from what column in where.

Comment: @sammywemmy the current df has values in the column `val`

Comment: @sammywemmy failing that, I don't understand what point you're trying to make, the example seems clear to me

Comment: if you can, kindly edit your post and add more details, especially around how you calculated 6/29, 9/26 ... cos I read it differently.

Comment: @sammywemmy I have added info.

Comment: in the dataframe, the count for x is 4, the sum of val for a is 18; for b sum of val is 26. what am i missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208013/discussion-between-baxx-and-sammywemmy).

Comment: Something like this? `df=pd.DataFrame({'where': np.repeat(np.array([['a'], ['b']]), 6), 'what': np.tile(['x','y','z'], 4) , 'val': [1,3,2,5,4,3,5,6,3,4,5,3]})`
Using groupby `(df.groupby(['where', 'what'])['val'].sum()/df.groupby(['where'])['val'].sum()).values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df['what_where_group'] = (df.groupby(['where', 'what'], as_index=False)['val']
                            .transform('sum')
                            .div(df.groupby('where')['val']
                                   .transform('sum'), 
                                 axis=0))

df
```

Output:

```
   where what  val  what_where_prop  what_where_group
0      a    x    1                6          0.333333
1      a    y    3                7          0.388889
2      a    z    2                5          0.277778
3      a    x    5                6          0.333333
4      a    y    4                7          0.388889
5      a    z    3                5          0.277778
6      b    x    5                9          0.346154
7      b    y    6               11          0.423077
8      b    z    3                6          0.230769
9      b    x    4                9          0.346154
10     b    y    5               11          0.423077
11     b    z    3                6          0.230769
```

***Details:***

First `groupby` two levels using what and where, by using `index=False`, I am not setting the index as the groups, and `transform` sum.  Next, groupby only where and `transform` sum.  Lastly, divide, using `div`, the first groupby by the second `groupby` using the direction as rows with `axis=0`.

---

Another way:

```
g = df.set_index(['where', 'what'])['val']
num = g.sum(level=[0,1])
denom = g.sum(level=0)
ww_group = num.div(denom, level=0).rename('what_where_group')
df.merge(ww_group, left_on=['where','what'], right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   where what  val  what_where_prop  what_where_group
0      a    x    1                6          0.333333
3      a    x    5                6          0.333333
1      a    y    3                7          0.388889
4      a    y    4                7          0.388889
2      a    z    2                5          0.277778
5      a    z    3                5          0.277778
6      b    x    5                9          0.346154
9      b    x    4                9          0.346154
7      b    y    6               11          0.423077
10     b    y    5               11          0.423077
8      b    z    3                6          0.230769
11     b    z    3                6          0.230769
```

Details:

Basically the same as before just using steps. And, merge results to apply division to each line.

Comment: thank you - I'm curious about your use of `as_index=False` (in the `.groupby) and `axis=0` (in the transform), are there any particular reasons for choosing these?

Comment: @baxx Did this help you?

Comment: absolutely - thank you, personally I think the first example is the most pandas-y? Would you personally prefer the first approach? I was going to add some additional context, but this does answer the original question. Thanks :)